# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client'

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

Getting error if I use the below line of code.

This is as per react guide code is written - [upgrade-guide](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
import React from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from "./components/App";


const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
root.render(<App tab="home" />);
```

But if I change the code as mentioned below then it works.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
// import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from "./components/App";


// const container = document.getElementById('app');
// const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
// root.render(<App tab="home" />);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Not sure why getting this error.

I tried below solution to update node with its dependencies as mentioned in the page :- [Link](https://stackoverflow.com)

tried
Sol-1

```
$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
$ ncu -u
$ npm install
```

and

Sol-2

```
$ npx npm-check-updates -u
$ npm install
```

but got the error.

Error for Sol-1 & 2

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.1.6
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"5.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```